Best Way to Link Node Values Across Materials in Blender?
I'm looking for a more efficient way to update multiple materials that share similar nodes and values. I have six different materials, each built with the same node setup but with different base colors. What I want is a method to edit one material and have those changes automatically apply to all the others without manually copying and pasting drivers for every single value.
For example, in my current setup, I have a "Hue/Saturation/Value" node with four adjustable values. Instead of manually creating a driver for the "hue" value and pasting it into five other materials, then repeating the process for the remaining values (saturation, value, etc.), I'm hoping for a way to link or copy the entire node so that all its values automatically sync across materials.
I also use nodes like "Noise Texture" that have multiple values, and manually syncing each one between materials feels incredibly time-consuming. Is there a way to copy a node or driver so that all the values are linked and automatically update across materials?
I’d appreciate any suggestions for a faster workflow or if there’s a tool or method I might be missing!
Thanks in advance for the help!


I believe I may have found a workaround for my issue. However, if there’s a more efficient solution, I would appreciate your guidance.
To maintain consistency in my question, I used the same node as an example. I duplicated the noise texture and HSV nodes, placing them above the original nodes. Next, I copied each value driver and pasted them into the duplicated nodes. After transferring all eight drivers, I selected both duplicated nodes and grouped them into a NodeGroup. I then copied and pasted this NodeGroup into the five other materials, replacing the existing nodes. I hope the accompanying screenshots clarify my explanation. Now I'm able to change material #1 and all other 5 different materials, change the way I like.

